# eclipse GTS Invalid remote: origin

Tags: eclipse, git, grails

I have been trying for many months go get eclipse, of any sort, to work with git hub.  I have git bash installed, this works, I have tortoise git installed, this works perfectly also.  I have putty, and use pageant it to load my ssh key.

I'm currently using GTS (grails) version of eclipse. When I import an existing project which I just cloned with tortoise git, it picks up the git details.  But when I try to fetch or pull or push from within eclipse, it always says:

Invalid remote: origin

googling this, most people say its an ssh config issue. This article: http://www.bashedupbits.com/2013/04/fixing-ssh-connection-problems-in-egit.html has a potential solution, but when I get to the bit when it says connect using putty to git@github.com, the putty session simply dies, so cant get further.  I have the key loaded in pageant.

Git command line, and tortiose git work perfectly.

Any ideas?

GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoisePlink.exe

I tried converting they putty ppk to an openssh type key, and "added" it in the preferences->general->network connections->SSH2->"add private key".  didnt help.

In

```
preferences->Team->Git->configuration->"repository settings"
```

I see:

```
Remote
  origin
     fetch: +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
     puttykeyfile: C:\Users\me\my.ppk
     URL: git@github.com:MyCo/myproj.git
```

Not sure what else can be done?

Comment: If you're doing Groovy/Grails development, I strongly recommend you consider IntelliJ instead. It's support for Groovy/Grails is far superior to GGTS and it also has excellent support for Git/GitHub

Comment: Intellij is way out of my price range.

Comment: Well, I just tried the community edition of intellij.  i can see would be a huge and expesnive learning curve, but tried out its git features.  It fails also, with "fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly".  git bash and tortoise git work perfectly still.

Comment: Got github working with intellij, only to find intellij (community edition) has no grails support what so ever.  E.g. under tools menu is a "groovy console" but no grails.  Googling around, this seems to only be available in the licensed version.  So eclipse with no git working, or intiellij with with no grails support.

Comment: There is also the option of paying for the ultimate edition of IntelliJ. You can try it for free for 30 days to see if you think it's worth it.

Comment: I'm not sure this is an SSH issue, I got it with HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer: the ssh engine may be part of the problem. You can switch the engine GGTS is using by setting the GIT_SSH environment variable before Eclipse starts.

Another alternative is that since Eclipse has to commit against a local repository first, stick to local stuff in Eclipse and simply run the remote push from the command line when you are done.

IntelliJ is good, but GGTS is also fine for developing Grails applications. I don't know why some folks are so religious about their choices. There are some points in GGTS that are not published very well by anybody. Check my blog post "Grails & STS: Avoiding Build Problems" at askjoelit.com.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the github repository.
2. clone the repository to copy it into your clipboard.
3. Go into eclipse.
4. Open the git perspective.
5. Right click to see the option to paste repository path or URL.
6. Paste the clipboard into eclipse.
7. Follow the wizard prompts.

   You should now have a cloned repository in eclipse.

Comment: thanks, but this is not the problem.  the repo url is correct. Its some kind of ssh issue, but debugging that is rocket science.

Comment: did you try setting the repo up to use passwords?